# Hive: Convert string datetime with missing seconds in "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hive, hiveql, cloudera

I'm using the following code to convert a string datetime variable to datetime, but the converted string is missing SSS part.

Code used:

```
cast(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(oldtime, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") as timestamp) as newtime
```

The outcome:

2019-03-08T18:28:36.901Z is converted to 08MAR2019:18:28:36.000000

Some other oldtimes in string:

```
2020-03-09T16:05:06:827Z
2020-03-09T16:03:19:354Z
2020-03-11T16:03:57:280Z
2020-03-10T16:02:57:642Z
2020-03-10T16:04:07:455Z
2020-03-10T16:04:09:737Z
2020-03-10T16:03:57:280Z
2020-03-10T16:02:46:816Z
```

The SSS part '901' is missing in the converted time. Would like help on keeping the SSS part since I need to sort the records by their exact time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`from_unixtime`**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) is always until **minutes**`(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)` to get `millisecs` we need to do some workarounds.

- we will extract the `millisecs` from the old_time using **`regexp_extract`** then `concat` that to `from_unixtime` result and finally cast to `timestamp`.

**`Example:`**

```
select old_time,
timestamp(concat_ws(".", --concat_ws with . and cast
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(old_time, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), -- from_unixtime and unix_timestamp to convert without millisecs
regexp_extract(string(old_time),".+\\.(.*)(?i)z",1))) as newtime from --regexp_extract to extract last 3 digits before z then concat
(select string("2020-03-11T21:14:41.335Z")old_time)e

+------------------------+-----------------------+
|old_time                |newtime                |
+------------------------+-----------------------+
|2020-03-11T21:14:41.335Z|2020-03-11 21:14:41.335|
+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

Your sample data have `:` before milliseconds, Try with below query:

```
select old_time,
    timestamp(concat_ws(".", --concat_ws with . and cast
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(old_time, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), -- from_unixtime and unix_timestamp to convert without millisecs
    regexp_extract(string(old_time),".+\\:(.*)(?i)z",1))) as newtime from --regexp_extract to extract last 3 digits before z then concat
    (select string("2020-03-11T21:14:41:335Z")old_time)e
```

Comment: `timestamp(concat_ws(".", FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(oldtime, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), regexp_extract(string(oldtime),".+\\.(.*)(?i)z",1))) as newtime` This is what I used, but the newtime are all appear to be missing.

Comment: @lydias, Seems correct to me! Could you add some `oldtime` column data to the question?

Comment: just added some examples

Comment: @lydias, your data have `:` before millisecs.. try with `timestamp(concat_ws(".", FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(oldtime, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), regexp_extract(string(oldtime),".+\\:(.*)(?i)z",1))) as newtime`

Comment: IMHO way too complex transformation in this case... regexp_replace alone will do.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `'T'` with space `' '` remove `'Z'` and replace last `':'` with dot, like this :

```
  select regexp_replace('2020-03-09T16:05:06:827Z','(.*?)T(.*?):([^:]*?)Z$','$1 $2\\.$3');
```

Result:

```
2020-03-09 16:05:06.827
```

Read also this answer if you need to convert to different format, preserving milliseconds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59645846/2700344

Comment: @lydias it hive it is compatible w timestamp. If necessary, you can easily cast: cast(regexp_replace(...) as timestamp)

Comment: @lydias But you can directly insert string in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS format into timestamp column without explicit casting. You really need to cast it in some rare cases. Also timestamp(...) can be used instead of cast(... as timestamp)

Comment: could you help me with another format of time ? In the form of `03-18-2020 17:27:02:153`  I tried to use `select concat_ws(':',from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split('03-18-2020 17:27:02:153','\\.')[0],'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')),split('03-18-2020 17:27:02:153','\\.')[1])`  It is not giving me the milliseconds.

Comment: I can open another question if you want me too.. I just feel the community may get annoyed by my timestamp questions..

Comment: @lydias one possible solution is to use regexp_replace: `select timestamp(regexp_replace('03-18-2020 17:27:02:153','(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{4}) (\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}):(\\d*)',
                      '$3-$1-$2 $4.$5'))` You can use some other method for conversion, you just need clear understanding what each function exactly does.

Comment: @lydias the best we have is offficial docs https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-TimestampstimestampTimestamps. And there are numerous rgexp tutorials and online testers like https://regex101.com/ in the internet.